# Text input with currency icon in the center

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a input element for currency where there is a currency icon always at the center (but it adjusts according to the number of digits)

Something like:

[image]

This is what I've come up with:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', resizeInput);
resizeInput.call(input);

function resizeInput() {

  this.style.width = this.value.length + "ch";
}
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.currency_input {
  width: 10em;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

input {
  min-width: 10%;
  max-width: 80%;
  padding: 0.1em;
  margin: 0.1em;
  border: 0;
}

input:focus,
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="currency_input">
  <span> $ </span>
  <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4">
</div>
```

Is there a better way? Things I haven't taken into considerations? Making it more responsive to be able to resize well? (Of course I will validate input later on)

Comment: I don't understand the units being used. We start out with `width: 10em`, but then we switch from `10em` to `NNNch` ?!? These are digits, so using `ch` all the time seems appropriate. And if `-ms-transform` is to support IE9 or something, we really need a comment explaining the impact and when we can delete such support. A `maxlength` of `4` is maybe on the small side if people paste in comma / dot punctuation like `1,000.00` or even `$1,000.00`. Display what was entered, and worry about validating it later.

Comment: Regarding `ch` I thought that it meant to have width of a character so I knew that I want the text input to grow by character size every time, and about the `-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`, I copied it from somewhere else and I will remove . How would you improve it?

Comment: I mean how would you make it to act as "one unit" when resizing for example?

Comment: I think using `em` (rather than e.g. `px`) is Good. I think using `ch` is Good. Both will adjust when user alters the font size. However, they express different things. So use `em` consistently throughout. Or in this case, given that we're displaying digits, better to use `ch` throughout. Just don't switch from `em` to `ch` is all I was saying. (I anticipate that digits will all render with same width.)

Answer (score 0):

May be something like

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.currency_input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(calc(100% - 0.5em),-50%);
}

input {
  width: 75%;
  border: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="currency_input">
    <span> $ </span>
    <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To me, this is not a code review but an alternative solution that is not within the scope of this platform.